# How to get body parameters in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Well I had just started programming in node.js. I am stuck at one place.

I am getting my request parameter like

```
response: --------------------------e2a4456320b2131c


sent
--------------------------e2a4456320b2131c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="is_test"

true
--------------------------e2a4456320b2131c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="success"

true
--------------------------e2a4456320b2131c--
```

How can i fetch all this params :

**is_test** , **success** and etc.

Here is my code :

```
var express = require('express'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
                            var body = "";
                            request.on('data', function (data) {
                                                  body += data;
                                              });
                            request.on('end', function() {
                                                console.log('response: ' + body);
                                            });
                        );
```

Comment: I know that i need to use bodyParser but how can i use. that's i dont know

Comment: `app.use(bodyParser.json());` well, it's not json, so ... have you tried the other options? raw, text or url encoded?

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure the router to handle the request. Take a look at the hello world example of express docs http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Moreover if you are sending data in the body you are looking for a http post method.
Example:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  const body = req.body;
  /*Body logic here*/
  res.status(200).end();
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
})
```

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. The code you posted it's incomplete, can you extend It to show the entire app intialization?

Comment: Here I have prepared a similar app like yours where you can send the post data as json or as form-data: https://gist.github.com/catacs/fd01a482118c282b82ffeb01f418c535